# Android- Reschelude alarm

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, intentservice

I have a Intent Service that conect with a server once a day and it works fine, just like the example in android tutorial.
Since it just poll the server once a day, I have a doubt.
What happens if the service tries to connect the server and the user is not online?
I miss that day or there is a way to reschedule the alarm at runtime and try to connect when the user is online?

Here is my code:
obs: I call setAlarm (context) in my launcher activity

```
  public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SampleAlarmReceiver alarm = new SampleAlarmReceiver();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            alarm.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}



public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleSchedulingService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


       alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
               SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60*1000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , alarmIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }



public class SampleSchedulingService extends IntentService {
    public boolean serviceGetNews;

    public SampleSchedulingService() {
        super("SchedulingService");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Utils.serviceGetNews(getBaseContext());
        SampleAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }
    public static void sendNotification(String msg, Context context) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, NewsActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify your usage case a bit better.  Are you already using `AlarmManager` to fire a `BroadcastReceiver` which then starts your service?  Is your `Service` set to automatically start via some other mechanism?

Comment: I post the code that I am using. It is a copy from the developers tutorial to connect with server using IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 questions, the answer to one is dependent on your `Service` implementation.  The first is about the `Alarm`.  Once you have set your alarm and `PendingIntent`, it will be broadcast at the correct time regardless of the sleep state of the device or user interaction.  You've also set it up to be repeating, so it will also be re-scheduled to be sent again at approximately the same time each day.  Your second question about the user interaction and the service contacting a server is completely up to your `Service` implementation.  If you need you service to re-try sooner than the next alarm, you would need to build in that logic.

Comment: If I create two alarms, one repeating once a day and another once a hour and choose wich one to use it doed the job?
There is a good solution for this case?